# MySql extract counters grouped by date

Tags: mysql

I have a table where I store some API requests. Each request has a status code and a `created_on` timestamp (not unix timestamp) representing when it was created.

In my application I want to build a graph and show the user the amount of requests that were performed each minute.

I'm trying to count the requests per minute and also extract the date of those requests down to the minute of course but ignoring the seconds.

If a timestamp `2017-09-27 00:33:44` is inserted and many other requests are being stored in the minute `33` but with different seconds I want to ignore those seconds and get this result:

`` 2017-09-27 00:32:00` : 1 (requests)
2017-09-27 00:33:00` : 4 (requests) ``

Is there a way to do this or I should break the `created_on` field down to year, month, day, hour, minute and then group by those?

I prepared an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1b20f8) as an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

E.g. Using your fiddle:

```
 SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created_on,'%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:00') minute 
      , COUNT(*) total 
   FROM api_request 
  GROUP 
     BY minute;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try :

```
SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING(created_on, 1, 16), ':00'), COUNT(*)
FROM table
GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL can group not only by data directly, but also by values computed from data. This immediately leads to a powerful and elegant solution:

```
SELECT timestamp, COUNT(*)
FROM table
GROUP BY YEAR(timestamp),
         MONTH(timestamp),
         DAY(timestamp),
         HOUR(timestamp),
         MINUTE(timestamp)
```

This selects the count and a corresponding full timestamp for the respective minute. This may or may not be sufficient for your case because it does not show the minute directly, but just a *timestamp including seconds* which lies *within that minute*.

From that timestamp, you can of course easily compute the minute, but the other answers already give you the minute without further effort, so they might be better for your case.

On the other hand, I *think* (but don't know for sure and can't test at the moment) that my solution might be quite fast.

Comment: How are you going to know which COUNT corresponds to which minute?

Comment: @Strawberry I see. Thanks for the hint and +1. You are right. I'll ad this.